# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DAIC\Desktop\React_CodeHelp\BackendMDb\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, middleware, bcrypt

'AuthZ_1_Codes\authapp\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DAIC\Desktop\React_CodeHelp\BackendMDb\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.0
PS C:\Users\DAIC\Desktop\React_CodeHelp\BackendMDb\AuthN & AuthZ_1_Codes\authapp>
[image]

This is my package.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "authapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```